# Is there a way to traverse an OptiX 7 acceleration structure to find the geometry closest to a given point?

Tags: raytracing, optix

I know this isn't the primary goal of OptiX but it is relevant when ray marching (sphere marching) signed distance fields so I figured I'd try. I created my own BVH for this originally but I was hoping to benefit from all the recent ray tracing work and RTX acceleration.

I will assume some basic familiarity with the OptiX 7 API.

My initial attempt involved setting the `optixTrace` ray direction to `{0, 0, 0}` but this only triggers intersections for shapes where the ray origin is inside the AABB (makes sense). I then set the ray direction to `{inf, inf, inf}` which seemed to trigger intersection calls for every primitive regardless of AABB distances or reported `tMax` values.

I played around with a few other combinations of ray directions and `tMax`/`tMin` values and I considered the various `OPTIX_RAY_FLAGS` but nothing seemed like it might work.

Ideally, it would be nice to query only bounding boxes that are within `tMax` distance from the ray origin. This is obviously a different check than a ray-aabb intersection but I was curious if there might be some API flags/masks/functionality I'm missing that would allow for this. Direct access to the acceleration structure hierarchy could help here too but I didn't see anything about that in the programming guide.

Comment: Just a comment -- there are only a handful of Optix questions on [SO] and you might struggle to get the attention of someone who could answer this. Consider another venue if you are in a hurry for a solution

Comment: @talonmies Yeah good point. I'll give the NVIDIA developer forum a go as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully one of us answered this on the OptiX forum, but just to address the question here:

It would be nice, and this is a common question, but unfortunately no, there is not currently a way to do a single nearest neighbor query or a single k nearest neighbors (KNN) query using the OptiX 7 geometry acceleration structures. These structures are currently limited to finite directional ray queries.

There is a paper that explores using OptiX to do a radius search using multiple ray samples: https://abasilak.github.io/papers/journals/jcgt2021/paper.pdf